# Jquery getting wrong response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

```
    function submitData()
    {
     var id = jQuery("input[name=Id]").val();
     var review = jQuery("input[name=review]").val();
     var dataString = 'id='+ id 
                      +'&review ='+ review;
     alert(dataString);
     jQuery.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "<?php echo base_url();?>mycontroller/myfunction",
             dataType: "json",
             data : dataString,
             success: function(e) {
                alert(e);
             }
      });
  };
```

IN Controller-

```
funciton myfunction()
{
    $data = array("id" => $this->input->post('id'),
          "review" => $this->input->post('review')
            );
   var_dump($data); 
}
```

In console i am getting  wrong response,
it's redirecting to other page.
and i am getting response from these page,
i checked these controller name and method name.

Comment: what do you mean by wrong response?

Answer (score 0):

you have syntax error in your function

```
  function myfunction()
        {
            $data = array("id" => $this->input->post('id'),
                  "review" => $this->input->post('review')
                    );
           var_dump($data); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark.

`var dataString = 'id ='+ id +'&review ='+ review;`

There is an extra space just before the "=" sign.

Can you try removing that, like so?

`var dataString = 'id='+ id +'&review='+ review;`

**Example check**

without space in parameter - Works

http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=something&format=json&pretty=1

with space in parameter - Doesn't work

http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q%20=something&format=json&pretty=1

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var id = 1;
     var review = 'test';
     //var dataString = 'id='+ id 
                      //+'&review ='+ review;
    // alert(dataString);
     jQuery.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/admin/myfunction",
             dataType: "json",
             data :{id:id,review:review},
             success: function(e) {
                alert(e);
             }
      });
```